# Create word count of text using hashmap

Tags: java, for-loop, count, hashmap

I am trying to create a program as a tutorial for myself for hashmaps. I ask the user into text and try to split it into hashmaps and then increase the count if the word repeats. This is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
public class TestingTables
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      {
      String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any text.");
      String[] splitted = s.split(" ");
      HashMap hm = new HashMap();
      int x;

      for (int i=0; i<splitted.length ; i++) {
         hm.put(splitted[i], i);
         System.out.println(splitted[i] + " " + i);
         if (hm.containsKey(splitted[i])) {
             x = ((Integer)hm.get(splitted[i])).intValue();
             hm.put(splitted[i], new Integer(x+1)); }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I input "random random random", I get:
    random 0
    random 1
    random 2

What do I need to change so I get:
    random 3
Also, do I need to use an iterator to print out the hashmap, or is what I used OK?

Comment: Why do you call `hm.put(splitted[i], i);`?

Comment: @MiserableVariable I found the syntax on the Java API and it was the variable that they were using in the example. I just forgot to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initialization is wrong `hm.put(splitted[i], i)`.
You should initialize to 0 or to 1 (to count, not to index).

So do this loop first.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            if (!hm.containsKey(splitted[i])) {
                hm.put(splitted[i], 1);
            } else {
                hm.put(splitted[i], (Integer) hm.get(splitted[i]) + 1);
            }
        }
```

Then just do one more loop (iterate through the keys of the HashMap) and print the counts out.

```
        for (Object word : hm.keySet()){
            System.out.println(word + " " + (Integer) hm.get(word));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
public class TestingTables
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      {
      String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any text.");
      String[] splitted = s.split(" ");
      Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      int x;

      for (int i=0; i<splitted.length ; i++) {
         if (hm.containsKey(splitter[i])) {
            int cont = hm.get(splitter[i]);
            hm.put(splitter[i], cont + 1)
         } else {
            hm.put(splitted[i], 1);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Your Map declaration is wrong, remember the correct way to implement a Map.

Comment: His map declaration is not wrong, he just does not use generics (which is not recommended but is not wrong too).

Comment: @peter.petrov Oh okay, I've never seen that declaration before.

Comment: @Vannens I believe this came up with java 5 release.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, its a pretty simple implementation..

```
        Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int x;

    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {

        if (hm.containsKey(splitted[i])) {
            x = hm.get(splitted[i]);
            hm.put(splitted[i], x + 1);
        } else {
            hm.put(splitted[i], 1);
        }
    }

    for (String key : hm.keySet()) {

        System.out.println(key + " " + hm.get(key));
    }
```