# Turn string into a JavaFX chart of character usage

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program in Java to show how many of
each character are contained inside of a TextArea using a BarChart.

I wrote a method that returns an "XYChart.Series" containing the
character and how many times it is used inside the TextArea,

However, every time it is called via the button event it is hooked to
it just returns an error to the tune of

```
"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 100, Size: 0"
```

Here is the method I wrote

```
private XYChart.Series stringIntoSeries(String text)
{
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray(); // char array of characters contained in string
    List<List> usageList = new ArrayList(); // list to contain character usage

    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {
        char c = chars[i];
        if(usageListHasChar(usageList, c)) // checks if character character has an entry in the list
        {
            int uI = usageListCharIndex(usageList, c); // finds index of the entry
            List l = (List)usageList.get(uI);
            l.set(1, (int)l.get(1)+1);
            usageList.set(uI, l);
        }
        else // if not create new entry
        {
            List l = new ArrayList();
            l.add(c);
            l.add(1);
            usageList.add(l);
        }
    }

    XYChart.Series s = new XYChart.Series(); // new series to contain character usage
    s.setName("");
    for(int i = 0; i < usageList.size(); i++) // add characters and amount of times used
    {
        List l = usageList.get(i);
        char character = (char)l.get(0);
        int usage = (int)l.get(1);
        s.getData().add(character, usage); // adds character and times used to series
    }
    return s; // returns the series once characters and usage are added which is then added to a BarChart
}
```

The error I am getting is on this line specifically

```
            s.getData().add(character, usage); // adds character and times used to series
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `List::add(int index, E element)`, try this.

```
s.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(String.valueOf(character), usage));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,  Is there anything I could improve on?

Comment: I think changing the `usageList` to `Map<Character, Integer>` makes it a more general implementation. Because `Map` can find index faster than `List<List>`.

Comment: Refer to this post. [Create word count of text using hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849512/create-word-count-of-text-using-hashmap)